Chat event #2 - planning?
So, after chat event number 1 went fairly well I think, I hereby propose we have chat event number 2.
The date and time is yet to be decided. With Christmas nearly upon us for those who celebrate it, this time of year gets very busy, but I think we can sneak in a meeting before then? (Or slightly after)?
For this event I propose we discuss both of:

Book reviews. By this I mean those who would like to recommend a book, or would definitely post a given book in a "favourite book" question instead do so in chat. Others can then ask "does it discuss favourite topic" and so on.
Creating awesome tag wikis including the the recommended books.
We might also include "must-read papers" perhaps?

The idea is to generate a wealth of introductory / good information for our most popular tag wikis.
Thoughts? Got a different topic you'd really like input on? At the last event Stack Exchange employees:
 
came along. Hopefully they or other community/comms team members will pop in next time too, so there may well (hopefully will) be a chance to ask them questions too.

For me slightly after Christmas (i.e. 26th to 2th) is bad, as I hope to be away then. But from the topics, it's not strictly necessary for me to be there.
